# Worst Case Big O runtime

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

Can someone help me find the worst case big-O runtime of the following algorithm in terms of `n`?

```
// precondition: A contains only positive numbers
public int[] four(int A[])
{
    int n=A.length;
    int[] B = new int[n];
    int max;
    for (int k=n-1; k >= 0; k--) {
        max = findMax(A);  //call to findMax above
        B[k]=A[max];
        A[max]=-1;
    }
    return B; 
}
```

Comment: depends on your findMax, otherwise it's just O(n), where n is the length of A.

Comment: How is `findMax()` implemented?

Answer (score 0):

```
// precondition: A contains only positive numbers
public int[] four(int A[])
{
    int n=A.length; //constant operation
    int[] B = new int[n]; //constant operation
    int max; //constant operation
    for (int k=n-1; k >= 0; k--) { //iterates through n times
        max = findMax(A);  //call to findMax above //will take complexity of O(n) assuming A is scrambled, 
        B[k]=A[max]; //constant operation
        A[max]=-1; //constant operation
    }
    return B; //constant operation 
}
```

This entire operation will take O(n^2) time as the loop is ran O(n) times with an operation inside that takes the time complexity of O(n) to complete assuming findmax() will take O(n) which is usual in the case that A[] is a scrambled array

This itself looks to be selection sort using 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your code depends on the complexity of `findMax()`.

As you algorithm counts one time from `n-1` to `0`, the time-complexity is `O(n⋅f(n))`, where `f(n)` is the complexity of `findMax()`.

`A` is assumend to be an unsorted, since you are sorting it. So `findMax()` is probably a linear search with a complexity of `O(n)`.

So the overall complexity would be `O(n²)`.